# How to customize backend authentication page of October CMS?

Tags: authentication, octobercms, octobercms-backend

I'm trying to customize the backend of October CMS. I'm using a plugin called Backend Skin: it hallows to customize October backend recreating folder structure inside your theme. So the core is not touched.

I have succesfully load a new css that act on authorization page (auth.htm), but now I've need to edit the form html and I'm not able to customize this section, which is contained in signin.htm and loaded with function `<?= Block::placeholder('body') ?>` inside of auth.htm. Code below:

```
<div class="layout-row">
 <div class="layout-cell">
  <h1 class="oc-logo"><?= e(Backend\Models\BrandSetting::get('app_name')) ?></h1>
   <div class="outer-form-container">
     <?= Block::placeholder('body') ?>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Those function go on call the original signin.htm and not my signin.htm.

I have read the documentation of October, but I can't understand to manage this code: `<?= Block::placeholder('body') ?>`.
How can I tell to October to load my new signin.htm located in  themes/mytheme/backend/controllers/auth/signin.htm (same structure of original signin.htm located inside modules/backend/controllers/auth/)?

The plugin author says there's no need to change the path of files, since they are placed inside the same structure of original backend. But for singin.htm it doens't work.

I hoper you can give some feedback about this.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are almost right but you also need to make sure its inside module.

means for layouts it pick up direct path `your_theme/backend/layouts/auth.htm`

> For module inner controller you need more specifications.

so your correct path for `signin.htm` should be like this

> themes/mytheme/**backend**/views/modules/backend/controllers/auth/signin.htm

I guess author also mentioned it as well in docs https://octobercms.com/plugin/cyd293-backendskin

its little confusing but you will surly get idea

```
themes/mytheme/backend <= main folder as we put all overriding thing here

                      /views <= view files not layouts or assets

                             /modules <= yes modules 

                                     /backend <= yes backend module

                                             /controllers/auth/signin.htm
                                             // finally auth controller's signin.htm
```

I guess this will make you understand how it works, now you are able to override that form html.

> **for some wired reason in my windows 10 machine path looks like this not sure why**

```
your_theme\backend\views\ules\backend\controllers\auth\signin.htm
--------------------------^ this
```

Try this may be it will work.

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion. I have changed the path as you have esplained, but it doesn't work. the auth.htm carry on call original signin.htm.

My actual signin.htm structure: themes/mytheme/backend/views/modules/backend/controllers/auth/signin.htm

Any idea?

Thank you very much

Comment: can you check i updated answer with `win 10` correction let me know if it can help you.

Comment: Thanks, I have contacted also the plugin author and it said to update to the last version (23 september) and now it works. Thank you for your time